# Script to make file hashes and track changes

Tags: python, database

I'm fairly new to python and decided to build something useful (I believe). So I made this script to track changes in user's files with DB with ability to "Accept changes", so end-user might track which files were removed/added/changed. This db then is being used in Django project.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I'm still learning python.

Atm project is located there:
https://github.com/Tehtehteh/script.py/tree/jatinga 
I apologize for russian commit messages (this is test branch).

Code:

```
import os
import sqlite3 as lite
from hashlib import md5
from datetime import datetime
import time
import argparse
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm
from configparser import ConfigParser


# ------------------- INIT CONFIG IF NOT EXISTS, ADD IN SECTIONS IF EXISTS ------------#
def initConfig(path, users, extensions, config_name):
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    if os.path.exists(config_name):
        cfg.read(config_name)
        excludes = cfg['MAIN']['excludes'].split("\n")
        extensions_conf = cfg['MAIN']['extensions'].split('\n')
        with open(config_name, "w+", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            cfg_new = ConfigParser()
            cfg_new.read(config_name)
            cfg_new.add_section('MAIN')
            cfg_new['MAIN']['Users'] = '\n'.join(set(users) - set(cfg['MAIN']['excludes'].split('\n')))
            cfg_new['MAIN']['extensions'] = '\n'.join(extensions_conf)
            cfg_new['MAIN']['excludes'] = '\n'.join(excludes)
            cfg_new.write(f)
    else:
        with open(config_name, "w+", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            cfg.add_section("MAIN")
            cfg['MAIN']['Users'] = '\n'.join([x for x in (os.walk(path))][0][1])
            cfg['MAIN']['extensions'] = '\n'.join(extensions)
            cfg['MAIN']['excludes'] = ''
            cfg.write(f)


# ------------- GET TUPLE OF USERS, EXTENSIONS -------------------------#

def initEverything(config_name):
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    cfg.read(config_name)
    users = cfg['MAIN']['Users'].split("\n")
    extensions = cfg['MAIN']['extensions'].split("\n")
    excludes = cfg['MAIN']['excludes'].split("\n")
    return users, extensions, excludes


# ------------- GET LIST OF USERS DIRECTORIES (STR) --------------------#

def initUsers(path):
    for x in os.walk(path):
        yield x[1]


# ---------------------- RECURSIVE FILE SEARCH (ARGUMENT IS USER DIRECTORY (absolutepath)) -----------__#

def get_filepaths(directory):
    file_paths = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return file_paths


# --------------------- CREATE FILE HASH, ARGUMENT IS ABSOLUTE PATH TO FILE -------------------------#

def createHash(path_to_file, BLOCKSIZE=1024):
    hasher = md5()
    if not path_to_file.endswith("~"):
        with open(path_to_file, "rb") as filepath:
            buf = filepath.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = filepath.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            return hasher.hexdigest()[:16]


# --------------------- TEST FUNCTION FOR OUTPUTTING USERS IN DB ---------------------------------__#

def getUsersFromDb(db_name):
    with lite.connect(db_name) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute("select * from Users")
        except Exception as e:
            with open("error.log", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
                log.write(str(e) + " ".join(str(datetime.now())) + "\n")


# --------------- MAKE DB INCLUDING TABLES IF NO DB FOUND ------------------ #

def initDBFromScratch(userlist, extensions, path, db_name):
    with lite.connect(db_name) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute("create table Users (name TEXT primary key not null)")
            cur.execute(
                "create table File (path TEXT primary key not null, old_hash TEXT, new_hash TEXT, flag_exists INTEGER,"
                "date_checked datetime, accepted INTEGER, name TEXT, foreign key(name) references Users(name) on delete cascade)")
            for user in userlist:
                cur.execute("insert into Users values (?)", (user,))
                for file in get_filepaths(os.path.join(path + user)):
                    if file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
                        cur.execute("insert into File values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (file, '', createHash(file), 1,
                                                                               time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                                                               0, user))
        except Exception as e:
            with open("error.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
                log.write(str(e) + " ".join(str(datetime.now().time())) + "\n")
        finally:
            con.commit()


# ------------------- CREATE HASH FOR NEW USERS ---------------#

def userCreated(user, extensions, cur, path):
    try:
        cur.execute("insert into Users values ('{}')".format(user))
        for file in tqdm(get_filepaths(os.path.join(path + user)), unit='File'):
            if file not in [x[0] for x in cur.execute("Select * from File").fetchall()] and file.endswith(
                    tuple(extensions)):
                cur.execute("insert into File values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (file, '', createHash(file), 1,
                                                                       time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                                                       0, user))
    except Exception as e:
        with open("error.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
            log.write(str(e) + " ".join(str(datetime.now().time())) + "\n")
    finally:
        with open("success.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
            log.write(
                "Successfully added new user({}) and his files @  ".format(user) + str(datetime.now().time()) + "\n")


# ----------------- UPDATE DB IN CRON ------------------------#

def updateDBCron(userlist, extensions, excludes, path, db_name):
    with lite.connect(db_name) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        try:
            print("Trying to delete users from exclude config:")
            for exclude in tqdm(excludes, unit='User'):
                cur.execute("Delete from Users where name=?", (exclude,))
                cur.execute("Delete from File where name=?", (exclude,))
                with open("success.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
                    log.write(
                        "Successfully deleted exclude " + exclude + " in db at " + str(datetime.now().time()) + "\n")
            print("Trying to fetch users file")
            for user in tqdm(userlist, unit='File'):
                if user not in [x[0] for x in cur.execute("Select * from Users").fetchall()]:
                    print('Creating new user', user, ' and fetching his files.')
                    userCreated(user, extensions, cur, path)
                else:
                    for file in get_filepaths(os.path.join(path + user)):
                        if file not in [x[0] for x in
                                        cur.execute("Select * from File where name='{}'".format(user)).fetchall()] \
                                and file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
                            cur.execute("insert into File values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (file, '', createHash(file), 1,
                                                                                   time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                                                                   0, user))
                        elif file.endswith(tuple(extensions)) and createHash(file) != cur.execute("Select *"
                                                                                                  " from file where path='{}'".format(
                            file)).fetchall()[0][1]:
                            cur.execute(
                                "Update file set new_hash='{0}' where path='{1}'".format(createHash(file), file))
                        for N_file in [x[0] for x in
                                       cur.execute("Select path from file where name=?", (user,)).fetchall()]:
                            if N_file not in get_filepaths(os.path.join(path + user)):
                                cur.execute("Update file set flag_exists=? where path=?", (0, N_file))
        except Exception as e:
            with open("error.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
                log.write(str(e) + " " + str(datetime.now().time()) + "\n")
        finally:
            con.commit()
            with open("success.log", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as log:
                log.write("Successfully updated db at " + str(datetime.now().time()) + "\n")


# ----------------- MAIN FUNC -------------------------------#

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("path", help="Top directory for user's directories to check files in")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path = args.path
    init_users = []
    init_extensions = (".php", ".js", ".html", ".css")
    try:
        init_users.extend(filter(lambda x: not os.path.isfile(x), os.listdir(path)))
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error encountered: ', e, file=sys.stderr)
        return
    config_name = "config.ini"
    db_name = "Monitor/test.db"
    initConfig(path, init_users, init_extensions, config_name)
    users, extensions, excludes = initEverything(config_name)
    if not os.path.exists(db_name):
        initDBFromScratch(users, extensions, path, db_name)
    else:
        updateDBCron(users, extensions, excludes, path, db_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage is simple:

```
python script.py %path_to_directory_with_user_directories%
```

Comment: Are there any good reasons why git is not fit for your use case? Implementing your own VCS is a nice task but if there were some reasons that made doing so a necessity then you should probably list them.

Comment: It's not exactly VCS, because it doesn't store old data. Or any kind of data in particular. This script just builds hashes of files, inserts it into db which then proceeds to django to make simple track of files for user.

Comment: So if there's a change we don't want to "accept", we won't be able to do a rollback?

Comment: That's correct ! I think I didn't brought enough explanations about this script and examples where it will be useful. For example, if we have server which has a lot of users (i.e. sites) stored in /var/www/. And we want to track those user's files (employee logins as one of those users and edit files: php, html, css etc). Admin goes to this dashboard and sees that file was changed on some date and asks employee about that. That is simple use of this script :)